# Putty не выводит русский текст в терминал

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, requests, vds

Putty не выводит русский текст в терминал. На локальном компьютере всё работает. Ставлю на сервер и пишет ошибку:

```
async def hello():
 print('привет')
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Ошибка:

```
print('\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Решил проверить кодировку с помощью sys и locale.

**Локальный компьютер:**
utf-8
cp1251

**Сервер Ubuntu:**
iso8859-1
ISO-8859-1

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134809/discussion-on-question-by-pshpth-sht-putty------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в Putty, который я использовал для подключения. Проблема решилась, когда я изменил стандартный UTF-8 на latin-1 в настройках Putty

Comment: Может лучше на сервере поменять кодировку на utf-8. Не знаю как в бубунте, а в дебиан можно выполнить команду `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. Возможно потребуется перезагрузка. Можно прописать в файле `/etc/default/locale` `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` (при условии что русский язык установлен в системе установкой пакета locales и командой dpkg-reconfigure locales). Я наоборот всегда перевожу путти в режим UTF-8